# One way linked list and unwanted first element afrter filling

Tags: c++, c, data-structures, linked-list, structure

I've got a problem with my one way linked list. It's wrote in C.

For input:

> 3
>
> 4 5 6

Output is

> 0 4 5 6

So the 0 is unwanted. What am I doing wrong, wrong passing list? It's looks like that in Add() function first "if" isn't done. But why, becouse passing list is empty.

[ideone link to code](http://ideone.com/kyVy5o)

Here is some code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct ELEMENT{
    int dane;
    struct ELEMENT *next;
}LIST;

void Add(LIST *FIRST, int x){
    LIST *ptr=FIRST,*el;

    el=(LIST*)malloc(sizeof(LIST));
    el->dane=x;
    el->next=NULL;

    if(ptr==NULL){
            ptr=el;
    }else{
        while(ptr->next!=NULL){
            ptr=ptr->next;
        }
        ptr->next=el;
    }
}

void Show(LIST *FIRST){
    LIST *ptr=FIRST;

    while(ptr!=NULL){
        printf("%d ",ptr->dane);
        ptr=ptr->next;
    }
    while(ptr!=NULL){
        ptr=ptr->next;
        free(ptr);
    }
}

LIST *HEAD=NULL;
int main()
{
    int i,counter,data;
    printf("Give me some data: \n");
    scanf("%d",&counter);

    for(i=0;i<counter;i++){
        scanf("%d",&data);
        Add(&HEAD,data);
    }

    printf("\nMy items:");
    Show(&HEAD);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: note : `&HEAD` type is `LIST**`.

Comment: Add log in Add() or GDB and trace it ti see what's wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

E.g to fix

```
void Add(LIST **FIRST, int x){
    LIST *ptr=*FIRST,*el;

    el=(LIST*)malloc(sizeof(LIST));
    el->dane=x;
    el->next=NULL;

    if(ptr==NULL){
            *FIRST=el;
    }else{
        while(ptr->next!=NULL){
            ptr=ptr->next;
        }
        ptr->next=el;
    }
}

void Show(LIST *FIRST){
    LIST *ptr=FIRST;

    while(ptr!=NULL){
        printf("%d ",ptr->dane);
        ptr=ptr->next;
    }
    ptr=FIRST;
    while(ptr!=NULL){
        LIST *tmp = ptr;
        ptr=ptr->next;
        free(tmp);
    }
}

LIST *HEAD=NULL;
int main()
{
    int i,counter,data;
    printf("Give me some data: \n");
    scanf("%d",&counter);

    for(i=0;i<counter;i++){
        scanf("%d",&data);
        Add(&HEAD,data);
    }

    printf("\nMy items:");
    Show(HEAD);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Now I understand my mistake and how it works. Thanks. Your code is working.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(ptr==NULL){
   ptr=el;
}
```

You got a problem here, in this case, you only change ptr, while FIRST remain the same, so eventually you are doing nothing but memory leak after return.

To solve this problem, you can return pointer, or pass pointer by address.